# Driving a 2.4v stepper with higher voltages?

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I went on a drunken online shopping spree around a month ago and today I'm the proud owner of a NEMA17 stepper and a dual H bridge L298N based motor driver.

The motor is bipolar and rated for 2.4V. The driver is 5V - 35V though, somehow I was under the impression that this would be OK.

From what I can understand is that I can use PWM to control the max amps of the driver board and I found some online comments claiming that as long as I limit the average current to what the motor can handle, I can run it with as high voltage as I want. Is that correct?

Normally I'd just hook it up and try it but it did take a whole month to ship here so I don't wanna kill it on first test with just 5V or something.

Comment: Lossy L298N’s have a large drop so 6~7V is better and 5V is safe but <2.4V to motor

Comment: The L298 is totally unsuitable for your task (it's used for fwd/rev control of DC motors). Buy a internally PWM based stepper current controlled driver based on chips such as the A4988 …DRV8825 or the larger TB6560/TB6600. These chips provide current sensing for the stepper motor and adjust their PWM to suit.

Comment: Indeed, it is entirely normal, **actually recommended** to use driver voltages many times the ohmic coil voltage - it's actually the only way to get reasonable performance at non-trivial step rates where inductance comes into play.  However, you need to use a current mode, typically chopping driver.  The L298 is just the power amplifier portion, paired with the companion L297 step synchronizer and current comparator it can make a chopping driver, though it's rather old and lossy bipolar technology.  The question should probably be closed as a duplicate of an existing stepper chopping question.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I ordered an A4988 based driver and a 35V step up converter, I'm gonna go FAST!

Comment: A boost converter may not be that great a combination with a chopping mode stepper driver.  It might work, but you're sort of putting two time domain switching systems together in odd ways.  The best stepper supplies are usually considered to be heavy-iron linear ones.